# React Error. this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the `state.time` after timer off, but I always get an error: `TypeError`: **this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString is not a function**. What is the problem is? Maybe anyone know...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './index.css';

class Demoss extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      time: new Date()
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerId = setInterval(() => this.setState({
      time: new Date()
    }), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
  }

  handleClick() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {time: prevState.time + 12}
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.time.toString().match(/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/g)) {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
          <p>{this.timerId}</p>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>clearTimer</button>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.time}</p>
          <p>{this.timerId}</p>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>clearTimer</button>
        </div>
      );      
    }

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Demoss />,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are adding 12 to your date, thereby converting it to a number. You can increment your date like so:

```
Date.prototype.addHours = function(h){
    this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}

this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {time: prevState.time.addHours(12) }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/127556/)

Comment: This is not a same what I need. I really need to use previous state of `time` and add to him a value of a `12`, by changing the `date` on a `string`. :(

Comment: man string variables doesn't have toLocaleTimeString function that's why you are getting that error

Comment: here you can see all the string methods

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

and here you can see all the Date methods

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

so when you add 12 to a date you turn that to a string and doesn't have toLocaleTimeString anymore